# powershell msi : the installation package could not be opened

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I can install node manually but using this Powershell command line within download directory (Windows Sandbox)

```
msiexec /i "node-v16.16.0-x64.msi"
```

I get error "the installation package could not be opened"

Comment: It's more reliable to use full path of MSI file. Also note that calling msiexec like this is asynchronous. The call returns while installation is still running. Use `Start-Process -Wait` for sychronous call.

Comment: Please check your current directory(pwd) while executing from powershell.